# OPEN A WINDOW WITH A TOOLBAR

Tags: url, extjs, tbar

I use a tbar in my grid and I want open a window when I click the button toolbar ..

But It is not work ..

My code is :

```
tbar : [
        {
           text : 'Accès à une campagne',
       handler: function(val, meta, record){ 
          return '<a href ="/gedeo/camp/dossier/id/' + id + '" target="_blank">' + val + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ],
```

If someone can help me please

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

```
{
   text : 'Accès à une campagne',
   handler: function(val, meta, record){ 
     window.open('/gedeo/camp/dossier/id/' + id);
   }
}
```